# How to reset a repository with SVN

Tags: linux, svn

I'm using SVN on my server and i don't know how i can reset my repository ?

There are a lots of data on this repository,i want reset this, and after make a new commit with a completly different folder.

Do you have any ideas ? How can i retrieve an empty repository ?

Thanks !

Comment: You want to delete all your repository history and data? This is **NOT** a good idea. I suggest you create a new empty branch and use it instead.

Comment: Whatever, i need a new repository, and all old datas are now useless so it's not a problem to delete these.

Comment: Under normal circunstances, you can just delete the repo (rm -rf) and create a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A repository is nothing else than a directory. Remove it manually and then run `svnadmin create` again. You'll also get a new UUID, which IMHO is a good idea: you won't confuse clients into thinking it's still the old repo where all history suddenly vanished.

Comment: It's ok for me, i'm the only one who use svn so... Thanks !

Comment: With "clients" I meant "Subversion clients". Committed revisions are not supposed to be able to disappear.